# setInterval loading html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to use this script to load "log.html" into a div element every 0.5 sec, to keep updated a chat log, but when the function is called the screen turns white and nothing else happens, it is not showing the newest posts, i only can see them if i refresh the window, thanks for your help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//If user submits the form
$("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});              
    $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
    return false;
});


//Load the file containing the chat log
function loadLog(){     
    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
    $.ajax({
        url: "log.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){        
            $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div               
            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
            }           
        },
    });
}

setInterval (loadLog, 500);
```

i'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "the screen turns white"? Does the HTML actually get returned? Are you sure you're replacing the right object?

Comment: Can you check the Network tab of your browser's developer tools if `log.html` did return your log. Also, check if there are any errors in the console.

Comment: yes i'm replacing the right object "#chatbox", the screen turns white... it does not load anything, but if i hit refresh, it loads again, and shows the new posts

Comment: Right here i can see an error but i don't know what it means "Uncaught ReferenceError: geovisit is not defined"

Comment: Yikes:  `$("#usermsg").attr("value", "");` Have you ever tried `.val("")` ?

Comment: You should not use Interval, get some long Ajax requests in there and you will start having things pile up.  Trigger a timeout when the call is complete. And make sure that the `html` is actually what you expect it is. Console is your friend.

Comment: .val("") works fine, but it stills doesn't solve the reload of "log.html", if i remove the setInterval function and just refresh the window it shows the newest posts...

Comment: Nevermind, this seems to be a problem in the server, i just try in other server and it runs fine!